# Spring Boot @RequestParameter Unexpected Behavior

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot MVC controller with the following @Request mapping. I'm using Thymeleaf for view.

```
@RequestMapping({"", "/", "index", "index.html"})
  public String index(){
      return "index";
 }
```

The index.html is present in resources/templates/index.html and I'm able to view it using http://localhost:8080

However, http://localhost:8080/index and http://localhost:8080/index.html results in White Label Error Page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for this is working. Do you have any other configuration?

Comment: No. Here is my repo https://github.com/ximanta/pet-clinic-web
I'm referencing https://github.com/springframeworkguru/sfg-pet-clinic and suprisingly it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure for your controller package is not correct. You should move the controller package to `guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.controller` so that Spring can find and use the Controller Bean.

[image]

But why is the index page showing when you enter `http://localhost:8080`? Spring automaticilly searches for an index.html for `http://localhost:8080` even if you do not specify any request mapping.

So move you controller package and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a / before every url. So instead of `index`, you need to change it to `/index`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not working. The referenced code is https://github.com/springframeworkguru/sfg-pet-clinic and it is working.
However, my code is not working https://github.com/ximanta/pet-clinic-web.git